# Does the W boson necessarily change an anti-fermion's flavor to its anti-neutrino counterpart?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

I'm writing the diagrams for the following process in Standard Model:
$$\nu_e + e^+\rightarrow \mu^++\nu_\mu+\gamma$$
I want to know if the W boson changes the flavor of $\mu^+$, for instance, necessarily to its anti-neutrino counterpart $\bar{\nu_\mu}$ or it can also change into $\nu_\mu$.

Comment: Muon and electrons are different flavors, not muons and muon neutrinos. As for what neutrino appears with a muon depends on muon number conservation.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought that within the leptons category we could distinguish between 6 different flavors: electron, muon, tau, electron neutrino, muon neutrino and tau neutrino. Am I wrong?

Comment: you can distinguish, but each lepton number is conserved in their own right. The reaction you write annihilates the flavor number so just energy and charge remains, an annihilation, ( like e+e-, anything can happen). It is conservation of charge  on the right that asks for a W+, , which then has to conserve whatever lepton  it creates with antilepton.

Comment: @annav  I think the OP is considering a $t$-channel process.

Comment: @JEB  depending on charge conservation in the specific process. anything that is not forbidden by conservation laws can happen, though it might be of very low probability.

Comment: @JEB Is this interaction allowed in the t-channel without introducing a flavor-changing neutral current?

Comment: @rob I think that is the point of the question?

Comment: @JEB Well, the present version of the question (v1) seems to be about tree-level charged current interactions.  But perhaps I haven't completely understood it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if the *W* boson changes the flavor of *μ*<sup>+</sup>, for instance, necessarily to its anti-neutrino counterpart $\bar  ν_μ$,  or it can also change into $ν_μ$.

No it does not, in the Standard Model. All vertices there conserve lepton number, so the virtual $W^+$ involved will decay to just $\mu^+ ~   ν_μ$.  To instead go to   $\bar ν_μ$ would violate lepton number by 2. The photon in the reaction will attach to any charged line in your diagram.

Equivalently, only $\bar ν_μ$ can go to $W^- ~ \mu^+$  while   $ν_μ$ can never do this.

When it comes to the (anti-)neutrino subscripts *μ,e,...*, in the standard model they merely *define* the special linear combinations of "real" neutrino mass eigenstates which couple the charged leptons *μ,e,...* to a *W*. (Some people like to call these *definitions* as enforcement of "lepton flavor".) They are fancy wavepackets  mutating among themselves in all neutrino oscillation experiments, but that is a longer, recondite story, far outranged by this question.

Comment: The last paragraph is indispensable for the complete picture when neutrino mutation shall NOT be ignored.